# Wine and the Print Screen Button

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, wine, print-screen

When I press the Print Screen button in a Wine window, Ubuntu handles the event. Is there a way to get a Windows-like behavior so that the screenshot is saved to the clipboard?

This probably isn't possible, since Wine's just a compatibility layer, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

---

**PAQ** (Probably Asked Question):

Q: *DLH, that's stupid. Why do you need that?*

A: *I'm writing a Python script that will screenshot a window and paste it into Paint. I will then be sending this script to someone else's Windows machine.*